# Defold создание игр

Tags: разработка-игр

всем добрый день, я бы хотел спросить у вас
кто может помочь с помощью в поиске ютуб канала где снимают создание 2 д игры
но интересно и понятно для новичка

Comment: Этот, как его.. Гоша Дударь, что ли. На Unity 3D вроде игры делал, ну там и 2D игры были. Доступно вполне излагал вроде. Пару лет назад я смотрел, может с тех пор что поменялось. Что такое Defold я не знаю ))

Comment: спасибо, defold это движок если что